How to recolor all Inno Setup WizardForm pages?
I'm trying to recolor the Setup Wizard and I want to know how to color every part of the installer. I can't figure out where to look for the other parts I haven't been able to recolor or how to call on them.
I tried doing:
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.Color := $6e6e6e;
  WizardForm.WelcomePage.Color := WizardForm.Color;
  WizardForm.InnerPage.Color := WizardForm.Color;
  WizardForm.TasksList.Color := WizardForm.Color; 
  WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Color := WizardForm.Color;
  WizardForm.FinishedPage.Color := WizardForm.Color;
end;

But some of the program remains the default white, including the bitmap images for WizardImage and WizardSmallImage.

For accessing all Inno Setup pages and controls programmatically, see:
Inno Setup built-in control names

Though the images likely have white non-transparent background. So you will have to change the images (either manually or programmatically).
